# My passport and visa has been stolen in USA

Tags: visas, usa, china, norwegian-citizens

I'm from Norway, backpacking from USA to Africa. Right now I'm on the way to Las Vegas, and in a couple of days I'm travelling to China. But ... my passport with my visa to China was stolen in San Antonio. I'm getting a new passport in San Fransisco, but not a new Chinese visa.

Do you know how to get a new visa, when I'm still travelling?

Answer (score 5):

Well It depends where you will be entering China. If you will pass by Hong Kong or Macau before entering mainland, getting a visa there would be the best option.

It took me about an hour the last time i got one issued at the Macau border(through CTS agency - https://www.ctshk.com/english/useful/chinesevisa.htm, which you can find in HK as well). You 'll need some proof of accommodation as well as a proof of exit(flight out for example) and that is it.

If your flight is already set for elsewhere in China, then you should apply in San Francisco, through the local consulate.
http://www.chinaconsulatesf.org/eng/lszj/t42285.htm

Answer (score 2):

After you get your passport in San Francisco, head over to the Chinese consulate **in the morning** to apply for you visa and hope they're willing--one day service is discretionary.  Your window is very tight, don't be surprised if you can't make it.